# Metadata comparison

Tags: metadata

Are there any  service/known option  to campare metadata on file system and some org and to identify what components have differencies. Is it possible to link this feature with Ci tool so it automatically detects what are the differencies and email them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any type of [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (CVS, SVN, GIT) in place at the moment?

Comment: Currently we have TFS

Comment: Ensure that exported orgs use same API version. I had the experience where org exported as v15.0 while the other as v30.0 because I believe the 'Enhanced User Profiles' was not selected - verify in `package.xml`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out Tquila's org. diff. http://www.tquila.com/blog/2015/01/08/org-compare

Edit: the SF Toolkit is now hosted at: http://sftoolkit.co/

Comment: Unfortunately no longer valid, because Tquila was acquired by Accenture. This link now redirects to the Accenture page.
Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: See updated post.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying out :
https://gearset.com/ 
a nice comparison tool that let you deploy changes as well...

Comment: I'm a developer at Gearset - thanks for trying it Yuval. We've also recently added dependency analysis,  which we're improving daily, and we have big longer-term plans focusing on CI and Git / other VCS integration. We're really responsive to feedback, so please let us know what you think!

Answer (score 2):

[SpringTool](https://springfive.com/springtool-offer/) can generate "interpreted" ORGs comparison reports (readable by non-technical people). It's not just a git based diff of metadata xml files but a visual report like that:

[image]

Results can be exported in a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use Beyond compare after extracting all the metadata in eclipse to compare .

Answer (score 1):

If you have any Version control tool/ source control tool, you can create two branches for the two different ORGS and compare them.

One more easy way is using eclipse, build a common package for the two ORGs and compare with each other.

Export the retrieved package into a file system or archived file.
Compare using KDIFF3. It is very easy to use and the best tool.

Answer (score 1):

I use copado deployer

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3dgGEAR

Does org diff, git integration and fast deployments.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to compare a standard/custom object and find out all the metadata differences.

I recently created a chrome extension for this and it is available @ https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/record-and-metadata-compa/laghgcpekjofijkmojnhfeiplbffaljp?hl=en-US

Answer (score 1):

We have app like [AutoRABIT](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000ptkwEAA) in appexchange which easier Metadata comparision and deployements. see below screenshot from this app.

[image]

Thanks,

Naveen.

Answer (score 0):

AutoRABIT has Salesforce Org Sync feature - which can send you scheduled / on-demand reports of differences at metadata level and also give you capability to view the differences at code level .
[AutoRABIT Org Sync](http://www.autorabit.com/blog/synchronize-salesforce-sandboxes-now-with-autorabit/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Test Pilot](https://www.testpilot.io/) (disclaimer: I'm a developer), you can compare metadata between any two orgs:

[image: Metadata diff with syntax highlighting]

We also have some CI features to email you when some changes were made that broke your test.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to set up the Force.com Migration Tool, then you can try the following tip:
https://www.securityzen.net/sf-tips

Once you get through the setup, just create a package.xml file and double click a bat file to do the comparison.